# How to update / insert a MongoDB sub document with Monger?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I'm using [Clojure's Monger](https://github.com/michaelklishin/monger) library to connect to a MongeoDB database.

I want to update, insert & remove subdocuments in my Mongo database. MongoDB's $push modifier lets me do this on the root of the searched document. But I want to be able to $push onto a sub-collection. Looking at [Monger's tests](https://github.com/michaelklishin/monger/blob/master/test/monger/test/updating_test.clj), it looks possible. But I want to be sure I can push to the child-collection of the 3rd parent. Can Monger do something like this?

```
    (mgcol/update mycollection { :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value" } { $push { "parent.3.child-collection" "fubar" }} )
```

Even better would be the ability to have a $where clause in my $push. Is something like this possible?

```
    (mgcol/update mycollection 
          { :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value" } 
          { $push 
              { { $where { parent.child.lastname: 'Smith' } } 
              "fubar" } } 
    )
```

But even on a basic level, when I try the following command in my repl, I get the below error.

1. The "fubar" database definitely exists
2. I'm definitely connected to the DB
3. The `{ :owner "fubar@gmail.com" }` criteria is definitely valid; and
4. I tried both `"content.1.content"` and `"content.$.content"`:

```
    repl => (mc/update "fubar" { :owner "fubar@gmail.com" } { $push { "content.1.content" { "fu" "bar" } } } ) 
    ClassCastException clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DB  monger.collection/update (collection.clj:310)
    repl => 
    repl => 
    repl => (clojure.repl/pst *e)
    ClassCastException clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DB
            monger.collection/update (collection.clj:310)
            bkell.run.run-ring/eval2254 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:46)
            clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6406)
            clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6372)
            clojure.core/eval (core.clj:2745)
            clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print--6016 (main.clj:244)
            clojure.main/repl/fn--6021 (main.clj:265)
            clojure.main/repl (main.clj:265)
            user/eval27/acc--3869--auto----30/fn--32 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
            java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:619)
```

Had anyone come across this and solved it?

Thanks

Comment: Isnt `$push` should be `"$push"`

Comment: I don't think that's right. If you look at [monger's tests](https://github.com/michaelklishin/monger/blob/master/test/monger/test/updating_test.clj), they use the ***$set*** operator (use 'monger.operators). I still tried it and got the same error. 

I've also tried different combinations of host and ports (27017). No dice… hmmm :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a three part question, with some inconsistencies and holes in the description.  So here is my best guess, hope that it is close.

I can get all three to work given schema matched to your update requests, see test/core.clj below for complete details.

First part: Yes, you can push to the child-collection of the 3rd parent, exactly as you have written.

Second part: You want to move your "$where" clause into the criteria, and use $ in the objNew.

Third part: Yes, your basic update works for me below, exactly as you have written.

The output of "lein test" follows at the bottom.  All the best to you in your endeavors.

test/core.clj

```
(ns free-11749-clojure-subdoc.test.core
  (:use [free-11749-clojure-subdoc.core])
  (:use [clojure.test])
  (:require [monger.core :as mg] [monger.collection :as mgcol] [monger.query])
  (:use [monger.operators])
  (:import [org.bson.types ObjectId] [com.mongodb DB WriteConcern]))

(deftest monger-sub-document

    (mg/connect!)
    (mg/set-db! (mg/get-db "test"))

    (def mycollection "free11749")

    ;; first part
    (mgcol/remove mycollection)
    (is (= 0 (mgcol/count mycollection)))

    (def doc1 {
        :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value"
        :parent [
                { :child-collection [ "cc0" ] }
                { :child-collection [ "cc1" ] }
                { :child-collection [ "cc2" ] }
                { :child-collection [ "cc3" ] }
                { :child-collection [ "cc4" ] }
            ]
        }
    )

    (mgcol/insert mycollection doc1)
    (is (= 1 (mgcol/count mycollection)))

    (mgcol/update mycollection { :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value" } { $push { "parent.3.child-collection" "fubar" }} )

    (def mymap1 (first (mgcol/find-maps mycollection { :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value" })))
    (is (= "fubar" (peek (:child-collection (get (:parent mymap1) 3)))))

    (prn (mgcol/find-maps mycollection { :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value" }))


    ;; second part
    (mgcol/remove mycollection)
    (is (= 0 (mgcol/count mycollection)))

    (def doc2 {
        :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value"
        :parent [
                    { :child  { :lastname [ "Alias" ] } }
                    { :child  { :lastname [ "Smith" ] } }
                    { :child  { :lastname [ "Jones" ] } }
                ]
        }
    )

    (mgcol/insert mycollection doc2)
    (is (= 1 (mgcol/count mycollection)))

    (mgcol/update mycollection { :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value" "parent.child.lastname" "Smith"} { $push { :parent.$.child.lastname "fubar" } } )

    (def mymap2 (first (mgcol/find-maps mycollection { :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value" })))
    (is (= "fubar" (peek (:lastname (:child (get (:parent mymap2) 1))))))

    (prn (mgcol/find-maps mycollection { :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value" }))

    ;; third part
    (mgcol/remove "fubar")
    (is (= 0 (mgcol/count "fubar")))

    (def doc3 {
            :owner "fubar@gmail.com"
            :content [
                    { :content [ "cc0" ] }
                    { :content [ "cc1" ] }
                    { :content [ "cc2" ] }
            ]
        }
    )

    (mgcol/insert "fubar" doc3)
    (is (= 1 (mgcol/count "fubar")))

    (mgcol/update "fubar" { :owner "fubar@gmail.com" } { $push { "content.1.content" { "fu" "bar" } } } )

    (def mymap3 (first (mgcol/find-maps "fubar" { :owner "fubar@gmail.com" })))
    (is (= { :fu "bar" } (peek (:content (get (:content mymap3) 1)))))

    (prn (mgcol/find-maps "fubar" { :owner "fubar@gmail.com" }))
)
```

lein test

```
Testing free-11749-clojure-subdoc.test.core
({:_id #<ObjectId 4fb3e98447281968f7d42cac>, :my-criteria-key "my-criteria-value", :parent [{:child-collection ["cc0"]} {:child-collection ["cc1"]} {:child-collection ["cc2"]} {:child-collection ["cc3" "fubar"]} {:child-collection ["cc4"]}]})
({:_id #<ObjectId 4fb3e98447281968f7d42cad>, :doc-criteria-key "doc-criteria-value", :parent [{:child {:lastname ["Alias"]}} {:child {:lastname ["Smith" "fubar"]}} {:child {:lastname ["Jones"]}}]})
({:_id #<ObjectId 4fb3e98447281968f7d42cae>, :content [{:content ["cc0"]} {:content ["cc1" {:fu "bar"}]} {:content ["cc2"]}], :owner "fubar@gmail.com"})

Ran 1 tests containing 9 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Comment: Ho-haa, that did the trick. I had to read up a little on the [$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator). But I'm much the better for it. Thanks :)

Comment: As a follow-on question.. Do you know how to remove a sub-document? I'm having a very difficult time doing this. I've outlined my dilemma and [various steps here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-mongodb/f9A8_lHh46E). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, I solved this follow-on question. You can see my solution outlined at the end of [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-mongodb/f9A8_lHh46E). Hope this helps.